# .Net creating reports from objects

Tags: c#, reportviewer, report

I wish to create reports (mainly PDF) from my business entity objects. The features I would like are:

1. Be able to define the report template in a designer
2. Be able to bind the report to a collection of business objects at run-time.
3. Export the report as PDF, Excel, (other formats such as XML, etc would be a bonus).

One such product is the ReportViewer that comes as part of Visual Studio. But I was wondering what other products were out there and the reasons you decided to use them instead of the bundled ReportViewer.

Comment: Just to recap: All of these provide the capability I was looking for: Stimulsoft, DevExpress XtraReports, FastReport.net, Telerik reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we are useing [stimulsoft](http://www.stimulsoft.com/) in our project,

[DevExpress XtraReports](http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/reporting/) is a famous reporting tool too

Also I like [this](http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/) open source lib for wpf reporting

Comment: +1 Was just answering that XTraReports was my preferred tool. It has a nice designer (runtime too), viewer, export capabilities, and works with simple properties for data.

Answer (score 2):

With **XtraReports** from **DevExpress** you can do this task easily:

```
public static XtraReport CreateReport(object data, string dataMember)
{
    XtraReport result = new XtraReport();
    result.Name "the_report_name";
    result.LoadLayout(@"c:\the_path\the_repx_template.repx");
    result.DataSource = data;
    if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataMember) ) { result.DataMember = dataMember; }
    return result;
}
```

Then you can use one of the following methods for **exporting** your report to the desired format (apply to **XtraReport** class):

```
public void ExportToPdf(string path);
public void ExportToRtf(string path);
public void ExportToText(string path);
public void ExportToXls(string path);
public void ExportToXlsx(string path);
public void ExportToHtml(string path);
public void ExportToCsv(string path);
public void ExportToImage(string path, ImageFormat format);
```

I have commented about this at: [Alternative to Excel as ASP.Net Report Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962887/alternative-to-excel-as-asp-net-report-generator/3964202#3964202)

Answer (score 1):

We are using [Telerik reports](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx).

We didn't hesitate since we were already using other Telerik components, but DevExpress XtraReports sounded really nice too.